# I can't modify the Angular form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this code in my component.ts, which fills the form with the data of the user who receives the id as a parameter

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

    async ngOnInit() {
    await this.makeForm(this.user);
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => this.userService.getUser(params.id).subscribe(
        resp => this.user = resp
      )
      );
  }
  async getUserId(id: number) {
    await this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.user = resp;
        this.formulario.controls.nombre.setValue(this.user['nombre'])
        console.log(this.formulario)
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
   makeForm(user) {
    console.log(user);
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  ngDoCheck () {
    if (this.user && this.formulario) {
      // tslint:disable: no-string-literal
      this.formulario.controls.name.setValue(this.user['nombre'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.lastname.setValue(this.user['apellidos'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.country.setValue(this.user['pais'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.city.setValue(this.user['ciudad'].toString());
    }
  }
  updateUser() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.formulario);
    if (this.formulario.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const data = {
      id: this.user['id'],
      nombre: this.formulario.value.name,
      apellidos: this.formulario.value.lastname,
      fechaNacimiento: date,
      pais: this.formulario.value.country,
      ciudad: this.formulario.value.city
    };
    this.userService.updateUser(data).subscribe(
      resp => this.router.navigate(['']),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the html code for an input

```
form [formGroup]="formulario" class="form">
            <table cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input
                      matInput
                      value="{{ user.nombre }}"
                      formControlName="name"
                      class="full-width"
                    />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

The problem is that the inputs remain with the user information and these cannot be modified, you cannot write to them and also not delete, they only remain static and I don't know what it could be. If I don't fill out the form, when I sent it the empty values appear.

Comment: Any console error in your browser?

Comment: Why are you setting the value using `value="{{ user.nombre }}"`? The value should come from the foem control. Remove that. Why are you resetting the values of the form controls at every detection change, with ngDoCheck()? What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using async and await even though you're not using any promise anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User[];
  formulario = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
   // tslint:disable-next-line: no-inferrable-types
   submitted: boolean = false;
  constructor(private userService: UserService,  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, 
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
                this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
                  params => this.getUserId(params.id)
                  );
               }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fillForm();
  }
   getUserId(id: number) {
    this.userService.getUser(id).subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.user = resp;
        this.fillForm();
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    console.log(this.user);
  }
  fillForm() {
    if (this.user && this.formulario) {
      // tslint:disable: no-string-literal
      this.formulario.controls.name.setValue(this.user['nombre'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.lastname.setValue(this.user['apellidos'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.country.setValue(this.user['pais'].toString());
      this.formulario.controls.city.setValue(this.user['ciudad'].toString());
    }
  }
  borrarUsuario() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    this.userService.removeUser(this.user['id']).subscribe(
      resp => this.router.navigate(['']),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
  updateUser() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.formulario);
    if (this.formulario.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const date = moment(this.formulario.value.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const data = {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      id: this.user['id'],
      nombre: this.formulario.value.name,
      apellidos: this.formulario.value.lastname,
      fechaNacimiento: date,
      pais: this.formulario.value.country,
      ciudad: this.formulario.value.city
    };
    console.log(data);
    this.userService.updateUser(data).subscribe(
      resp => this.router.navigate(['']),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

The biggest changes were, remove the ngDoCheck and start the form before the constructor, in addition to filling out the form when the user data is searched